# Node-RED: where do I find docs for RED.nodes.createNode/getNode/eachNode/

Tags: node-red

I may be blind, but I cannot find documentation for functions I've seen in many node implementations as there are:

- RED.nodes.createNode()
- RED.nodes.getNode()
- RED.nodes.eachNode()
- RED.nodes.originaFlow()

including important details concerning nodes shown in the editor and those actually used by the runtime.

Everything I found seems to be horribly outdated.

For that reason: where do I find up-to-date docs for the mentioned functions?

Comment: We don't have a lot of docs for the internals of the runtime. `createNode` is touched on in the 'creating nodes' docs. The others are internal functions. If you had specific questions, you may want to join the project slack/discourse and ask there.

Comment: well, thanks for the fast response. I had hoped not having to bother too many people by reading about these functions myself - but if there are no docs...there are no docs

Comment: Did you open a discourse topic for that? If yes > can you please add a link here?

Comment: no, not yet, but it sounds like a good idea

Comment: just for the records: I've just joined [discourse](https://discourse.nodered.org/) and created a [new topic for this question](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/where-do-i-find-docs-for-red-nodes-createnode-getnode-eachnode/51478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to not leave this question unanswered:

answers for this question and similar ones (dealing with the internals of Node-RED) may be found in [some postings written by Nick O'Leary for the Node-RED forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-can-i-set-the-error-indicator-little-red-triangle-of-a-node-in-the-editor/51481/7)

The following is just a copy from there:

**Everything that follows only applies in the editor. This is no equivalent in the runtime.**

#### Finding by name

There's no direct way to find anything by its 'name' - names are optional fields and can be left blank. They are also not unique. Under the covers you should be using the id field to reference other nodes.

```
let node = RED.nodes.node(id);
```

To get any nodes whose name property is set to a particular value:

```
let results = [];
RED.nodes.eachNode(function(node) {
   if (node.name === "HELLO") {
      results.push(node);
   }
});
```

(If you dig around the code, you'll see `RED.nodes.filterNodes` exists - that currently only filters on `z` and `type` rather than any other property... but it would be simply enough to update to handle any property... we have never needed it)

The above works for regular flow nodes. To do the same for Config nodes or Flows, you'd do the same but with `eachConfig()` and `eachWorkspace()` respectively.

##### Find connected nodes of a given node

```
let node = RED.nodes.node(nodeId);
let allConnectedNodes = RED.nodes.getAllFlowNodes(node)
```

If you just want the nodes that come 'before' or 'after' this one, you can do:

```
let allUpstreamNodes = RED.nodes.getAllUpstreamNodes(node);
let getAllDownstreamNodes = RED.nodes.getAllDownstreamNodes(node)
```

Additional information can be found in [another posting](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/how-can-i-set-the-error-indicator-little-red-triangle-of-a-node-in-the-editor/51481/12), which is also copied below (the first code line illustrates how to access a node by its internal id):

> how to find the name of the tab a given node is placed on

```
let node = RED.nodes.node(id)

let tab = RED.nodes.workspace(node.z) || RED.nodes.subflow(node.z);
```